# call keras model as a function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I tryied to test direct keras model call with a demo, the code is simple as below.

```
from tensorflow  import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=32, input_length=5))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(units=5, activation='sigmoid'))

f = np.random.randint(0,100, 5)
print(model(f))
```

It raises error:
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 160 but received input with shape (5, 32)`

Is the data I mocked format wrong or keras model doesn't support this kind of debugging/testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I made a foolish mistake.
The input should be batched called.
So change f with `f = np.random.randint(0,100, (1,5))` will work